# how to: save exe with bbfreeze

Tags: python, windows, user-interface, exe

I've had one course of computer science so far and now I'm playing around with some of the GUI's I've made.

I wan't to save my exam-GUI as an .exe/application that can run without python installed.
I have downloaded bbfreeze, as it seems to be the program working best in windows 7, but I have no idea how to do this, can anyone give me a hint or link to a how-to site.
Would be nice, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for bbfreeze is severely lacking. I would recomend using py2exe, cx_freeze, or pyinstaller instead. Off these if you are trying to make a *single* exe, pyinstaller is the easiest to use. cx_freeze and py2exe are very good, but they produce a series of files (dlls mostly) that the exe depends on.

To install Pyinstaller, follow the [manual](http://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/#installing-in-windows). It boils down to this: install [PyWin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/), then [Pip win](https://sites.google.com/site/pydatalog/python/pip-for-windows). In the pip win prompt, type in `venv -c -i  pyi-env-name`, and then `pip install PyInstaller`.